# Text outside of tikzpicture figure is somehow different/bolder - how to change it?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I managed to build this figure with tikzpicture, which is what I wanted, but I do not understand why the text outside of the pyramid looks different from the text inside and is bolder. I would like to achieve that the text outside and inside of the figure look the same. Is there any way to achieve this? This would really help me, I somehow couldn't figure it out myself or find similar questions... Here is MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{1.00\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (-3,0) {};
            \coordinate (B) at ( 3,0) {};
            \coordinate (C) at (0,4) {};
            \draw[name path=AC] (A) -- (C);
            \draw[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);
            \foreach \y/\A in {
                0/TextText,
                1/TextText TextText,
                2/TextText \\ Text,
            } {
                \path[name path=horiz] (A|-0,\y) -- (B|-0,\y);
                \draw[name intersections={of=AC and horiz,by=P},
                name intersections={of=BC and horiz,by=Q}] (P) -- (Q)           node[midway,above,align=center,] {\A}
                ;
                \draw[decorate, decoration={brace},thick] (-2.4,0.9) -- 
                node[left=2mm, pos=0.55] {\normalsize \text{Text Text Text}} 
                (-1.2,2.5);
                \draw[<-] (2.4,1) -- 
                node[right=3mm, pos=0.5] {Level 1}
                (3,1);
                \draw[<-] (2,1.5) -- 
                node[right=4.8mm, pos=0.5] {Level 2}
                (3,1.5);
                \draw[<-] (1.4,2.3) -- 
                node[right=7.5mm, pos=0.5] {Level 3}
                (3,2.3);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the text outside of the triangle 3 times on top of each other (once in each iteration of the loop). This will make the text appear thicker.

You should move the static text out of the loop:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
%    \resizebox{1.00\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (-3,0) {};
            \coordinate (B) at ( 3,0) {};
            \coordinate (C) at (0,4) {};
            \draw[name path=AC] (A) -- (C);
            \draw[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);
            \foreach \y/\A in {
                0/TextText,
                1/TextText TextText,
                2/TextText \\ Text,
            } {
                \path[name path=horiz] (A|-0,\y) -- (B|-0,\y);
                \draw[name intersections={of=AC and horiz,by=P},
                name intersections={of=BC and horiz,by=Q}] (P) -- (Q)           node[midway,above,align=center,] {\A}
                ;
            }
            \draw[decorate, decoration={brace},thick] (-2.4,0.9) -- 
            node[left=2mm, pos=0.55] {\normalsize {Text Text Text}} 
            (-1.2,2.5);
            \draw[<-] (2.4,1) -- 
            node[right=3mm, pos=0.5] {Level 1}
            (3,1);
            \draw[<-] (2,1.5) -- 
            node[right=4.8mm, pos=0.5] {Level 2}
            (3,1.5);
            \draw[<-] (1.4,2.3) -- 
            node[right=7.5mm, pos=0.5] {Level 3}
            (3,2.3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
%    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked very well!

Comment: @Horstfuchs You're welcome!